# Execute multiple SQL queries and sort the output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

Currently, I'm working on a project that requires me to execute 2 SQL queries, then I have to sort the output by date and id before writing the output of both queries to a table.

Sorting both queries in SQL with :

```
ORDER BY order.date DESC, order.id DESC.
```

Then appending the results in one variable that gets looped over by another part of the script. But executing the seperate queries will result in 2 blocks of sorted items that will not be sorted together when appending the results.

What would be a solution to get the data sorted properly?

Comment: Hint:  `union all`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (<query 1> UNION ALL <query 2>) ORDER BY order.date DESC, order.id DESC` where queries 1 and 2 don't have any order by in them (or they do it doesn't matter in the end)

Comment: Why do you need 2 seperate queries te get the data? The general idea of getting data with a query is to make it all into 1. This is more efficient.

Comment: if you don't want duplicate records use `UNION`

Comment: @Babydead Honestly, because I'm not really skilled enough to write that kind of SQL code yet. I'm a dev student still.

Comment: Neither am I. That's why I have a history of asking "How do I put these queries together into one?". As clearly, people are answering how to fuse them from the SQL side already. It's simply a lot easier than sorting out data afterwards. Especially when it comes to seperate sets of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT A.* FROM ((QUERY1) UNION ALL (QUERY2)) A ORDER BY A.date DESC, A.id DESC
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed, thanks a bunch (to @apokryfos as well for the nearly the same answer in the comment above!)